# Unable to upload to arduino

Tags: arduino-uno

I am coding my arduino for an upcoming robot competition. I have managed to upload my code and run it on my arduino once or twice, however now I am unable to upload code. I now receive the following message:

```
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
```

I have unplugged USB, pushed the reset button, checked all the settings (ports, programmer, etc), unplugged the arduino and even tried running basic code such as Blink. I've been searching for hours and now I'm not sure what to do. I am getting no response and I'm finding this really frustrating. Does anyone have any advice as to how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you checked the port and chose the right one? Sometimes if you unplug an arduino and then connect it back again it might choose different port.